# How to pass value from link to pop up?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am trying to pass a value to a popup window I have.
I am uploading a list of dealers with WP store locator plugin, each dealer has different email. So when clicking a button "Email dealer" I have a popup that should get a "data-attribute" value from the link.

So now I have Popup maker plugin that works on that link click. But I can't pass a value from the link.

Here's my js file for this click

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    console.log("Here's console output");  // I get this in console
    $('.emailDealerBTN').click(function(){
        console.log("Clicked button");    // Nothing in console
        emailDealer=$(this).attr("data-emaildealer");
        console.log(emailDealer); // Nothing in console

    });
});
```

And here is a code from store locator plugin that forms that button-link:

```
$listing_template .= "\t\t\t" . '<div class="button-wrapper"><a href="#" class="button-red button emailDealerBTN" id="emailDealerBTN" data-emailDealer=<%= formatEmail( email ) %> >Email a dealer</a></div>' . "\r\n";
```

So I tried to have same track on clicked button outside the code of "dealer locator plugin":

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    console.log("Here's console output");
    $('.emailDealerBTN').click(function(){
        console.log("Clicked button");
        emailDealer=$(this).attr("data-emaildealer");
        console.log(emailDealer);

    });
    $('.locator-cta').click(function(){
        console.log("Clicked Apply to become a dealer");
        link=$(this).attr("href");
        console.log(link);

    });

});
```

[Here's the result in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoKES.png)

I am not sure if the problem is with store locator plugin.
The JS file above is loaded **before** DOMContentLoaded. However, I was sure that "jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {" will give me an opportunity to check clicks after the document is ready. AND it works with the same button link outside the code of plugin.

Yes, I have checked other Q&A here on slack and other resources.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You want to pass `href` value in model or `ancho`r text in the model?

Comment: try like this:- `$(document).on( 'click','.emailDealerBTN' ,function(){
        var emailDealer = $(this).data("emaildealer");
        console.log(emailDealer);
    });`

Comment: You could use the jQuery .data(‘attribute-name’) method if you’re targeting a data-attribute for the particular link to add to the pop up

Comment: everything perfect in code. sometimes multiple click function defined in same or another file for that specific button so it'll executed that one. so check that kind of conflict are there or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the problem here is your `click()` event is called before the button is generated..

Use `.on()` jQuery method.

`.on()` allow to add events on dynamically loaded content.

Try This:-

```
$(document).on('click','.emailDealerBTN',function(){
    console.log("Clicked button");
    var emailDealer = $(this).data("emaildealer");
    console.log(emailDealer);
});
```

Comment: THANKS!!! I tried ".on('click', function(){" before...Seems to be no difference but it worked somehow.

Comment: if this worked then please accept the answer...  Happy to help...

Answer (score 0):

better you use element id as a selector. Try like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#emailDealerBTN').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('data-emailDealer'))
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried it as well. It doesn't work either.
Also, id supposed to be unique value comparing to the class when it is repeated

Answer (score 0):

Try using `on` event to make sure your script will still runs if the html element is added or modified dynamically. Its also a bad practice to define your variable globally.

```
( function($) {

    $(document).ready( function() {
        console.log('My script loaded')
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.emailDealerBTN', function() {
        var emailDealer = $(this).data('emaildealer'); // or $(this).attr('data-emaildealer');
        console.log('Clicked button');
        console.log(emailDealer); 
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by saying "globally"? I am sorry if it is a stupid question